# Certifying multiple PDF files simultaneously

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a digital certificate, with which I would like to certify more than a 1000 PDF files. I am using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro. Is there any way to do it all at once?  Currently I am opening every file one by one, certifying it and then saving it. Need to find a faster way of doing this.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Create a new action](http://www.evermap.com/ActionWizardX.asp) through [the actions wizard](http://www.ipex.org/files/tailor_your_adobe.pdf), then run it from the command line using the [AutoBatch plug-in from Evermap](http://www.evermap.com/AutoBatch.asp). It's not free.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What steps should the action contain? Is there any tutorial or sample?

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://www.signfiles.com/pdf-signer/

> The main function of PDF Signer is to sign PDF documents using X.509 digital certificates. Using this product you can quickly sign multiple PDF files (bulk sign) by selecting input and output directory. This is ideal for bulk signing of a large number of corporate documents rather than signing each one individually.

Or you can use:

> [Print2PDF](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/PDF/Print2PDF.shtml) can add multiple electronic digital IDs to PDF. This will allow you to verify and approve expense reports or any documents which need to be approved by more than one reader.